# What is mvcl design pattern in open-cart?

Tags: opencart

What is MVCL design pattern in open-cart, i heard about mvc (model , view , controller ) but don't understand what is MVCL stand for or what is this.

Comment: Good question, helped me to learn about Model View Controller Language (MVCL)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MVCL means **M**odel **V**iew **C**ontroller **L**anguage
The controller brings the text stored in the language file, and turns them into variables that can be echoed in the template file to displayed text. This is especially useful for managing translations.
[image]